# c++ array problems with Zeshan

Tags: c++

In this program, I am trying that when I write name DK, I see "Correct 
        Password" answer. But I always see "Incorrect Password", whether I write 
        DK or MK or any other name. Can someone please guide me? Please try to 
        explain 
        in easy words. I started learning c++ like a week ago. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    char name [6];
    cout << " Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    if (name == "DK")
    {
         cout << " Correct password"; 
    }   
    else    
    {
          cout << " Incorrect password.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also this code will not compile.

Comment: I never get the point of down voting these questions. He obviously tried. The guidelines to stackoverflow state: Be welcoming and do not expect people starting here to ask perfect question. I am kinda missing that attitude.

Answer (score 1):

`char name[6]` is an array of chars. Thus `name` returns the address of the first element of the array. `name == "DK"` compares the address of the first element with with the address of the string literal `"DK"`. That's not what you want. You should either use `std::string` instead of char arrays or you can use `std::strcmp` from `<cstring>` to compare char arrays. I recommend `std::string`s because they're easier to handle. Examples with `std::string`s are posted by other users.

An example with cstrings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char name [6];
    cout << " Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    if (strcmp(name, "DK") == 0)
    {
        cout << " Correct password"; 
    }   
    else    
    {
        cout << " Incorrect password.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```